# Open a file directly to emacs (by double-clicking)

Tags: macos, emacs, applescript

How would I go about setting all .rb files or all .py files to open in emacs if I double-click them; say, from the desktop?

I'm on OS X 10.6.2.

I have the script:

```
on open of finderObjects
    repeat with currFile in finderObjects
        set unixPath to POSIX path of currFile

        set base to do shell script "dirname " & unixPath
        set fname to do shell script "basename " & unixPath
        do shell script "cd '" & base & "';" & " emacs  " & fname

    end repeat
end open
```

But if I drag a file (text.py - just prints a line) on it, I get: 
emacs: standard input is not a tty

And I'm unsure of how to solve this.

Thanks!

EDIT: Solved with link: http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20031027142625782

```
set filecount to 0

on open filelist
    repeat with i in filelist
        set filecount to 1
        tell application "Terminal"
            set filename to do shell script ¬
                "perl -e \"print quotemeta ('" & POSIX path of i & "');\""
            do script "emacs " & filename & "; exit"
        end tell
    end repeat
end open

if filecount < 1 then
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "emacs; exit"
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: I think this would belong on superuser.com

Comment: The reason I didn't post it there is I'm assuming that it will involved a bash script – that seems SO-y to me. But move it if it doesn't belong!

Comment: In an ideal world it would go there. Sadly, I've yet to work in an environment where developers weren't expected to setup emacs themselves (or more likely, use some inferior editor....and *like it*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each type, select a file in the Finder, choose `Get Info` from the File menu.  In the Info window that opens, under the `Open with` section, choose the emacs app you are using (and it must be an app version), and then press `Change All..` .

If you are using the traditional curses emacs from the command line, you could build a small AppleScript app in the ScriptEditor or Automator action that would receive the files from the finder and open emacs with them.  Then use `Get Info` to associate the app with .rb and .py files.

EDIT: See this [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184236/on-mac-o-s-how-to-get-the-name-of-files-that-has-been-dropped-onto-apple-script) for one way to create an AppleScript launcher app: just modify the shell command to call emacs instead.

FURTHER EDIT:  Your script is almost there but you need to run the script under `Terminal.app`.  Try modifying it like so:

```
        launch application "Terminal"
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script "cd '" & base & "';" & " emacs  " & fname
        end tell
```

Comment: The issue here is I'm using the Terminal – if it were that simple, I'd have done it!

Comment: @Isaac Copper. In your question you mentioned clicking on a file to open it.  How are you doing this in the terminal?

Comment: As I said in the question - I am double-clicking from the desktop.

Comment: @Isaac: I've added a link to a recent SO answer that shows what you need to do.

Comment: @Isaac: A further edit to show running the script via Terminal.app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an OS X expert, but if emacs there is like it is on Unix and Windows it should have an [emacsclient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) utility for feeding new files into an already running emacs session.

[This previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945709/emacs-23-os-x-multi-tty-and-emacsclient) has some details on how to do this on a multitty setup. Perhaps some of that is applicable?